# How to access a rails array in javascript stored under assets

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, arrays, json, controller

I have an array defined in my rails controller:

```
str_array = ["Hi","hello"]
```

I need to access this array in my javascript file stored under assets.
I have defined a variable type of array of arrays in my js. I tried accessing like this but failed :

```
var js_arr = [<%= raw @str_array.to_json %>];
```

Is there any other way to access the rails array in my javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very clean way to pass stuff from RoR to JS is the [gon gem](https://github.com/gazay/gon).

No nasty printing variables with erb or such stuff.

You get an object called `gon` which you can pile data into in your RoR-controller. Add `include_gon` to your layout, and voilà - the gon object is available in JS too.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added a .erb extension to that JavaScript file?

Comment: Also, have a look at Gon: https://github.com/gazay/gon. Gon allows you to set JS variables from your controllers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will go through this and try this option.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways.

1) Pass it up to the javascript via ajax as necessary. (e.g on a Button Click or the like).

2) Put inline javascript in one of your view templates (erb, haml, or w/e) where you want to access it, and then pass the rails array with #{rails_array}.to_json in your method call.

The first is cleaner, more testable, and in the long term more maintainable. The second is easier to implement.

Comment: Hi Abraham.. Thanks for your answer.. Can you please make 1st point clear as i tried to put ajax part in my index.html.erb and pass array into my js but its not displaying on the page.